# How to Update TKinter Label Image Using Classes (Dynamic Update Using Config() Method)

Tags: python, tkinter, label, project

I want to update the image stored in the red_smiley_1 label.
I want to define my method 'change_row_one' so that I can use the Label.configure() method to update the image stored in this the Label widget.
How should i define my method?
I've included my current method which is giving me issues.
Thank you.

```
class Cube(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
  super().__init__()
  self.title("John's GUI Cube Application")
  self.geometry("300x180")
  self.resizable(True,True)

  container = ttk.Frame(self)
  container.grid(padx=10,pady=10,sticky='EW')

  cube_frame = CubeFrame(container).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='NSEW')

class CubeFrame(ttk.Frame):
  def __init__(self,container):
  super().__init__(container)
  self.red_smiley = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('./images/red_smile.png'))
  self.white_smiley = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('./images/white_smile.png'))
  self.yellow_smiley = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('./images/yellow_smile.png'))

  # Red Smiley Image Labels
  self.red_smiley_1 = ttk.Label(self,image=self.red_smiley).grid(row=0,column=0)
  self.red_smiley_2 = ttk.Label(self,image=self.red_smiley).grid(row=0,column=1)
  self.red_smiley_3 = ttk.Label(self,image=self.red_smiley).grid(row=0,column=2)

  # Image Label Buttons
  self.row_one_button = ttk.Button(self,text='Change Row 1',command=self.change_row_one).grid(row=0,column=3,sticky='WE')
  self.row_two_button = ttk.Button(self,text='Change Row 2',command=self.change_row_two).grid(row=1,column=3,sticky='WE')
  self.row_three_button = ttk.Button(self,text='Change Row 3',command=self.change_row_three).grid(row=2,column=3,sticky='WE')

  # Change Row One Image Labels
  def change_row_one(self):
    new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('./images/white_smile.png'))
    self.red_smile_1.configure(image=new_image)
    self.red_smile_1.image = new_image
```

Comment: On button click you are doing nothing, then how can it changes image?

Comment: I should clarify that I'm trying to use the button click to update the image stored in label 'red_smiley_1'. My initial approach to defining the 'change_row_one' method is as follows:

  def change_row_one(self):
    new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('./images/white_smile.png'))
    self.red_smile_1.configure(image=new_image)
    self.red_smile_1.image = new_image

Comment: You don't have to make new variable `(new_image)`, if you are using that same image of white_smiley. Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492839)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem.
When creating the label I used the grid() method all in the same line.
This was returning None.
Solution URL: [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
class CubeFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,container):
    super().__init__(container)
        self.red_smiley = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('./images/red_smile.png'))
        self.white_smiley = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('./images/white_smile.png'))
        self.yellow_smiley = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('./images/yellow_smile.png'))
        
          # Red Smiley Image Labels
        self.red_smiley_1 = ttk.Label(self,image=self.red_smiley)
        self.red_smiley_1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.red_smiley_2 = ttk.Label(self,image=self.red_smiley)
        self.red_smiley_2.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.red_smiley_3 = ttk.Label(self,image=self.red_smiley)
        self.red_smiley_3.grid(row=0,column=2)
        
          # Image Label Buttons
        self.row_one_button = ttk.Button(self,text='Change Row 1',command=change_row_one)
        self.row_one_button.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky='WE')
        self.row_two_button = ttk.Button(self,text='Change Row 2',command=change_row_two)
        self.row_two_button.grid(row=1,column=3,sticky='WE')
        self.row_three_button = ttk.Button(self,text='Change Row 3',command=change_row_three)
        self.row_three_button.grid(row=2,column=3,sticky='WE')

  # Change Row One Image Labels
    def change_row_one(self):
        self.red_smiley_1.config(img=<other image/self.white_smiley>)
```

First thing first, you are doing wrong while making new labels. You are making new label and setting the position of that label inline which will return `None` and that means you can't use those response  variable.  And you don't have to do `self.<function>` in command, function doesn't need self you can only write `<function>` only.

Comment: When I use your method after clicking the button, the label doesn't graphically show the new image i reference using the configure() method you mentioned in your solution. Thoughts?